# Erro ao publicar no iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service, iis

Estou com um webservice e faendo a publicação no servidor estou tendo a resposta do erro

Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Estranho que no local isso funciona normalmente e estou fazendo apenas um publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***POSSÍVEL CAUSA***

> Quando a estrutura 3.5SP1 é instalado e o ClickOnce armazenamento é usado para os primeiros arquivos cdf ms tempo talvez excluído. Isso pode ser causado pela exclusão da chave do registro HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\ClickOnce35SP1Update. Os arquivos ausentes do cdf ms fará com que o ClickOnce erroneamente compartilhamento forte chamado assembly com a mesma versão mas o hash de arquivo diferente.

***SOLUÇÃO***

> Para evitar o problema antes que ele aconteça Certifique-se de que todos os módulos (assemblies) compartilhados que você está usando em seu aplicativo ClickOnce atualizado tem uma nova versão do assembly.

Se o problema já ocorreu é necessário limpar o cache on-line executando "mage.exe – cc", desinstale todas as versões dos aplicativos instalados que podem ter um conjunto com nome de alta segurança com a mesma versão e reinstale o aplicativo.

Mage.exe está disponível em vários locais, incluindo o seguinte:

·         O.NET Framework 2.0 SDK. O.NET Framework 2.0 SDK está disponível como um componente da instalação do Visual Studio 2005 ou pode ser baixado do Centro de Download da Microsoft.

·         O Windows SDK para Windows Vista. O SDK do Windows para o Windows Vista pode ser baixado do Microsoft Download Center.

·         Visual Studio 2008. Versões mais recentes do Mage.exe e MageUI.exe são incluídos como um componente da instalação do Visual Studio 2008.

**PARA SABER MAIS:** https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/971052/the-located-assembly-s-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly